# Upgrade ubuntu 21.10 to ubuntu 22.04 "authenticating the upgrade failed. There may be a problem with the network or with the server"

Tags: 22.04, 21.10

Sorry I know there are lot of similar questions, but I can't seem to find the solution to my problem. I had not powered up my computer for a few weeks, and when I came back today I realized I could no longer download anything from apt or else, and realized Ubuntu 21.10 had ended. But when I try to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04, I have the message "Authentication failed: authenticating the upgrade failed. There may be a problem with the network or with the server". My internet connection works perfectly well, and I changed the parameters to download from the best server available, and yet nothing works, does anybody have an idea ? Thank you <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a script for it.

Use that:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/daboynb/linux_scripts/74a3785744d11abced39c5ba1ba29905b6a4dd05/upgrade_eol_to_jammy.sh && chmod +x upgrade_eol_to_jammy.sh && ./upgrade_eol_to_jammy.sh
```

Btw just to respect the rule to not post something that one day will be gone. This part should fix.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Change repos to old-releases.ubuntu.com 
text="deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-security main restricted universe multiverse"
sudo echo "$text" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
    
# Prerequisites
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core update-manager -y
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y 

# Download and run the ubuntu upgrade tool
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/jammy.tar.gz
tar -xaf jammy.tar.gz 
sudo ./jammy --frontend=DistUpgradeViewText
```